# Jenkins on AWS times out when trying to clone git repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on an AWS EC2 instance, port `8080`. When trying to clone a repo (via ssh), the cloning attempt times out with the error:

```sh
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.sharedtools.com/scm/mcflow/mcflow-java-commonlib.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.sharedtools.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

I added HTTPS port 443 to my list of inbound rules for the EC2's security group, and even allowed all inbound connections from everywhere, and am allowing all connections outbound, but am still seeing the error. Below is a screenshot of my security group's inbound and outbound configurations:

[image: Inbound rules]

[image: Outbound rules]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share your VPC and subnet architecture? NACL might be blocking the traffic. Or there might just be no route to public internet.

Comment: Can you reach the url yourself? That doesn't look like a bitbucket website.

Comment: @TTT It's a corporate site -- I'm thinking I can't access maybe because I need to configure my firewall?

Comment: If the site is not public, then you'd have to adjust the settings on the corporate site to allow connections from you, and the AWS server. Or, you'd have to know what settings are required in order to access it. For example, maybe you have to be on the proper internal network (via VPN) in order to access it.